How to sum data by input date, month and previous month
I'm trying to sum up data of selected date, month of selected date and previous month of selected date but don't know how to do. Below is my sample data and my expected Output:
Sample data:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('https://github.com/hoatranobita/hoatranobita/raw/refs/heads/main/Check%20data%20(1).xlsx', sheet_name='Data')
df

    COA Code    USDConversion Amount    Base Date 2
0   19010000000 26924582.44 2024-10-01
1   19010000000 38835600.44 2024-10-02
2   19010000000 46794586.57 2024-10-03
3   19010000000 57117346.49 2024-10-06
4   19010000000 69256132.98 2024-10-07
... ... ... ...
65  58000000000 38082130.88 2024-11-12
66  58000000000 38140016.13 2024-11-13
67  58000000000 38160089.27 2024-11-14
68  58000000000 38233974.54 2024-11-17
69  58000000000 38323598.99 2024-11-18

So if I select date of November (for example 2024-11-18, I want to group by selected date, month of selected date and previous month of selected date.
Output:
COA Code        2024-11-18  October         November
0   19010000000 42625047.24 1354513618.61   584813860.97
1   58000000000 38323598.99 820927014.08    456265522.64


So, you want to provide a date and get the value and that of the month and previous month? Can you have several COA codes per date?

The exact generalization of your question is not fully clear, but assuming that you want to group by COA Code, you could ensure everything is a datetime/periods, then select the appropriate rows with boolean indexing and between, finally perform a groupby.sum of those rows and concat to the original date rows.
Here as a function for clarity:
def get_previous(df, date, date_col='Base Date 2'):
    # ensure working with datetime/period objects
    date = pd.Timestamp(date)
    period = date.to_period('M')
    dt = pd.to_datetime(df[date_col])
    p = dt.dt.to_period('M')
    # select rows to keep
    m = p.between(period-1, period, inclusive='both')
    
    # produce rows with original date
    # aggregate previous and current month
    # combine and rename the columns
    return pd.concat([
          df[df[date_col].eq(date)]
           .set_index('COA Code')['USDConversion Amount']
           .rename(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
        
          df[m].groupby(['COA Code', p])['USDConversion Amount']
           .sum().unstack(date_col)
           .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strftime('%B')) 
          ], axis=1).reset_index()


out = get_previous(df, '2024-11-18')

Output:
      COA Code   2024-11-18       October      November
0  58000000000  38323598.99  8.209270e+08  4.562655e+08

NB. you can replace groupby.sum+unstack by pivot_table (df[m].assign(col=p).pivot_table(index='COA Code', columns='col', values='USDConversion Amount', aggfunc='sum')).

Thank you so much and yes, it will have several COA per day.

I'm sorry but I got InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects with real data. DO you know what's wrong with it?

@hoatran most likely you have multiple times the target date for a given COA. If this is the case you have to chose between joining the two tables that make the final one, or aggregating the first one.
